# Why does error come when I fit Keras in RStudio?

Tags: r, keras

I have tried multiple solutions that I found in Stackoverflow and GitHub, but none of them worked. I have a listed error when I try to fit the model:

> Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) :
> ValueError: in user code:
> C:\Users\USER\AppData\Local\R-MINI~1\envs\R-RETI~1\lib\site-

I have tried to install a thing below, but it did not want to install due to another error:

```
   devtools::install_github("rstudio/reticulate")
```

> Error: Failed to install 'reticulate' from GitHub:   (converted from
> warning) installation of package
> ‘C:/Users/USER/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpWO8ojY/file58b0477f394/reticulate_1.18-9000.tar.gz’
> had non-zero exit status

The problem like a yack-shaving. One after another. It appeared by itself without any reason.

Comment: Try `install.packages("reticulate")`

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! It is better to think of this community like you do for Wikipedia. Users come here with a specific question in mind, looking for a specific answer. Please edit your post title to ensure that it can be looked up by future users, the current title does not provide a description. I hop e you have a good time here!

Comment: @Phil , I tried it as well. It installed well but did not resolve a problem. This error comes when I fit 4 dim array x_train, and y_train is 2 dim. This error sometimes comes in another project, but I fit 2 dim x_train and y_train in there.  

P.s. as I mentioned, it did not happen before